# Scala - case class with 100 fields (StackOverflowError)

Tags: scala, case-class, scala-2.11

I created scala case class with 100 fields +- ,
When I'm trying to build the project (with gradle) , I'm getting error:

```
Cause: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
```

I'm using scala 2.11 , and found that in the past, there was a limitation of 22 fields. but it was fixed.

So why the build is failed?
(I tried to increase -Xss20m , but it didn't help)

Comment: Someone just reported this, either a project ticket or on SO. I think they had 200 fields for DB columns. They also tried huge stack for compilation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many fields does it take before this Stack Overflow error happens?

Comment: with 96 fields. (95 fields the build successful)

Comment: I've just got exactly the same on 2.11.8.
I can't even say there's a clear border where it starts getting broken.
Somewhere around 95-96 indeed, but sometimes it saw the build breaking with a smaller number (between 85 and 90).
So it doesn't seem to be bound to a specific number of arguments.

Comment: I also faced the same issue. Anyone with a solution ?

Comment: Also having this issue. I am also building with Gradle from within IntelliJ and apparently, I have troubles passing -Xss to scala compiler. Has anyone found a way?

Answer (score 4):

What worked in my case was setting -Xss in build.gradle script like this:

```
compileScala {
    options.forkOptions.jvmArgs += "-Xss4m"
}
```

Then I am able to compile app with case class having 100+ fields using scala 2.11.12. All the other settings (in IntelliJ Idea menus) were not effective.